# Suppose $f$ is a real-differentiable function on $[a,b]$ and suppose $f'(a)<c<f'(b)$. Prove then there is a point $x \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x)=c$

Tags: derivatives

This is what i have:

Put $g(t) = f(t) - ct$.

Then $g'(a)<0$ so that $g(t_{1}) < g(a)$ for some $t_{1} \in (a,b)$ and 
$g'(b)>0$ so that $g(t_{2}) < g(b)$ for some $t_{2} \in (a,b)$.

Hence $g$ attains its minimum on $[a,b]$ at some point x such that $a<x<b$.

Then, $g'(x)=0$, hence $f'(x)=c$

Comment: Please read the description of the tags before you add them to your question. This has absolutely nothing to do with the [maximum (modulus) principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle).

Comment: Some might consider it terse (for presumably an introductory analysis course); but it looks fine to me. Perhaps at the outset  point out that $g$ does have a minimum on $[a,b]$ and state why. Also, you might explain why the observations made in the second paragraph hold and explicitly state that they imply the minimum in fact occurs at a point in  $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29). You need to do a bit more work because it could happen that you have to pick $x=a$ or $x=b$.

Comment: It looks to me that the OP took care of the endpoints. He states, e.g., "$g'(a)<0$ so that $g(t_1)<g(a)$ for some $t_1\in(a,b)$" (so the minimum is not achieved at $a$).

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the [Intermediate Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). You can find a proof worked out searching Google or Youtube.

Also check out [Darboux's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29), which states:

> Let ${I}$ be an open interval, $f\colon I\to \mathbf{R}$ a real-valued differentiable function. Then $f'$ has the intermediate value property: If $a$ and $b$ are points in $I$ with $a\leq b$, then for every $y$ between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$, there exists an x in [a,b] such that $f'(x)=y$

Comment: We don't know if $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: Actually, it's known as Darboux's Theorem.

Comment: Yes I've updated my answer